php -v and php -i show different versions that phpinfo() and Plesk Control Panel
php -v and php -i both show that I'm running PHP Version => 5.4.16 on my CentOS 7 server. When I look at phpinfo() the PHP version is 7.4.33 (the correct version) which is the selected version through Plesk. The reason this is a problem is that I'm trying to install libssh2 but the make fails for the 7.4 version but is successful for the 5.4 version of libssh2.
How do I get the php versions to match-up? I need php -v to show 7.4.33 not 5.4.16.
The real problem I having is ssh2_connect is returning an undefined function call which I believe is due to not finding libssh2 libraries because I have the wrong version, 5.4 instead of 7.4, compiled.

You should ask yourself where that 7.4.33 is installed. Just search (e.g. using find) for it. Oh, btw, upgrade!

You can have more then 1 installed php instance
While domain can be set to use exact version, in terminal may be required to provide exact path to version u want to use

The website version is installed in /opt/plesk/php and is using /opt/plesk/php/etc/php.ini. When I run php -i |grep php the php.ini file it finds is in /etc. I'm a little concerned. I want the system version to be 7.4.33 but I don't want to crash my production server.

PHP generally has a separate package and install for CLI, usually named something like php-cli. Plesk may manage the web-facing version, but the CLI version is likely up to you to manage.

Ok. Thank you. I'll uninstall 5.4 and install 7.4. That should resolve the compiler errors I was getting ssh2

Was able to upgrade to php7.4 and install and compile ssh2 without errors. I turned on display_errors for the website in the correct php.ini file but it still shows 'Off' in phpinfo(). I have restarted apache a number of times. phpinfo() shows I editing the correct php.ini file but I can't turn on display_errors.

All is well. Finally figured out that to restart the web version of php I had to do it through the plesk control panel rather than the command line. I'm not smart enough to understand why there are two separate php installations on one server, why you can't just use the same php code for both. But it is what it is...
